# How to Make 3-Dimensional Curved to Flat Sheet

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

I wish to create a 3-Dimensional figure in either Adobe Illustrator of Photoshop that has a 2 curves in the foreground that transitions into a flat sheet along the z-axis.  The 3-dimensional sheet that I've created (below, from Illustrator) has the two curves (and the downwarp) extruded across the entire sheet, but I was wondering if there is a relatively straight-forward way to gradually flatten towards the back of the sheet.

What I've done thus far:  Made 2-D curved line, extruded the shape.  I also tried the Warp function in Photoshop, but I couldn't get just the back of the 3D structure to be flat.

Thanks for your input.

[image]

Comment: You should mention what type of program you are talking about, or what you've tried so far and why it hasn't worked. Maybe mention how you accomplished what you have so far. This can be easily created in Photoshop or Illustrator, but I don't think that's what you have in mind.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of details.  Edits are provided above.  You're correct that I hope to use either Illustrator or Photoshop to create an asymmetric 3D sheet with the two curves gradually flattening to a flat sheet.  Perhaps changing the shading could do the trick?

Comment: Neither of those are a 3d application. The tools you have do just whet they say nothing more. There is no magic tool to do this you have to manually draw this stuff.

Comment: @joojaa that's actually not true. Both of those applications have 3d capabilities. In illustrator the first effect is literally just called 3D and can be used to create what the question asks.

Comment: @Peacockerie No, they have simple effects that dont make them 3D (ie the image is still flat you can not extrude another shape and make a hole for example). But note the OP didnt ask at all what you answered, z axis is the one towards you. **He asked how to do [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/23Gue.png)** and as far as i am concerned it does not get 3D untill you can **do [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yQqIf.png)**. To acceuate the point I can do [following](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2dgiW.png) in Notepad Does that make notepad 3D capable? You can draw manually but that is not being asked.

Answer (score 1):

make the line you want, then outline the stroke so it looks similar to this: [image] 
Then go to the Effect option in the toolbar and select `3d>Extrude & Bevel` :[image]
Then you can tweak the depth settings and change the position however you want to achieve what you are looking for: [image]